# Error using pymtp and libmtp

Tags: typeerror, pymtp

I am new to programming on python and i am trying to create an application which uses pyMTP to communicate to an MTP device. However im getting this error and cant figure out the fix for it.

```
$ python c:/Users/Atul/Desktop/mtp.py
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Atul/Desktop/mtp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymtp
  File "C:\Users\Atul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pymtp.py", line 42, in <module>
    _libmtp = ctypes.CDLL(_module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Atul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Comment: Still broken with the same error message as of fall 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Think it is not a program, but a library, you have to import. Like once in python, import mtp  (or import pymtp, i don't know anymore). Please be aware pymtp is about 5 years old and does only run on python 2. I have been working on a python 3 version but it's not really complete because i found testing MTP software is extremely time consuming because the mtp interface is very, very slow at startup. I suggest to look at gMTP to transfer you files.